# How to place Forms controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, position, anchor, dock

I have a Form and I want to add two controls: a ComboBox and a ListView. The ComboBox has to occupy the upper part, while the ListBox **all the remaining space**.

Like in the following picture:

[image]

What have I to do? What are the right properties to modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new form, then add you two controls - the `ComboBox` and the `ListBox`. Now, first in the designer set the `ComboBox`s `Dock` property to `Top`. Then select the `ListBox` and set its `Dock` property to `Fill`. This will do what you require.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In this way my ListView fills the entire form... EDIT: I have to add first the ListView, and it works.